# Xamarin.iOS: NFC App Not Running in Simulator, throws error

Tags: xamarin.ios, core-nfc

I've built up an NFC based app over Xamarin.iOS which reads and writes data on an NFC tag.
It works without any issues when run on an actual iPhone connected over USB.
However, I need to check its UI on different screen sizes so I attempted running it on simulator. However, it throws some compile time errors, first one of which is -

/.../iPhoneSimulator/Debug/device-builds/iphone 8-14.5/mtouch-cache/registrar.h(58,58): Error GE71D2E27: no type or protocol named 'NFCTagReaderSessionDelegate' (GE71D2E27) (WRConnectApp.iOS)

and then few occurrences of 'expected a type()' which seem to be related.
When ran on a physical device, I see no such errors at all.
I also checked that the iOS version on the phone and on the simulator is same.

I can understand that the Mac doesn't have NFC and the app depends on NFC libraries which it might not be finding during simulation, but I couldn't find a way around.

Is there a way to do so? Or is there some other problem which needs to be sorted in the first place?

Comment: If you just want to test UI comment your NFC code and check the UI, NFC code wont run on a simulator, it will crash

Answer (score 0):

To test an app with NFC feature, a real device must be used instead of an iOS simulator

Comment: Does it make any difference @FreakyAli? You have mentioned same thing that I have answered.

Comment: It's an answer of the question asked here. If its not then what is the answer and why you have put the same in comment?

Comment: This is not an answer because if you read the question thoroughly you will notice that the OP already knows what the issue is he needs a solution that would make it run so that he can verify the UI. :)